# Errors when importing libgdx projects into eclipse

Tags: java, libgdx

I followed the libgdx project setup and when I imported the projects into eclipse, I got these errors and haven't had any luck searching around for a fix.

```
The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required                 .class files    MainActivity.java   /Spellcast-android/src/en/fred/spellcast    line 1  Java Problem
The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files    RobovmLauncher.java /Spellcast-robovm/src/en/fred/spellcast line 1  Java Problem
The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for java.lang.Object. Fix the build path then try building this project    Spellcast-robovm        Unknown Java Problem
The type com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files   GwtLauncher.java    /Spellcast-html/src/en/fred/spellcast/client    line 8  Java Problem
The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint. Fix the build path then try building this project   Spellcast-html      Unknown Java Problem
The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for java.lang.Object. Fix the build path then try building this project    Spellcast-android       Unknown Java Problem
```

Does anyone know what I'm missing?

Answer (score 7):

Try these, hopefully they will help.

Right click the project and go to Properties. In the properties window:

- Choose Android and make sure a
  version of Android is checked (I've imported projects before that
  were set up for a version of Android that I hadn't downloaded the
  developer tools for, so they wouldn't compile until I did this).
- Choose Java Build Path, and then the Order and Export tab. Make sure
  everything is checked.
- Choose Java Compiler and make sure you
  are compiling with Java 1.6.

Comment: I feel like a blind cactus but I don't quite understand what you're referring to when you say "make sure a version of Android is checked". Oh and also why should I compile with Java 1.6?

Comment: If you select the Android option in the properties window, there's a box on the right where you select which version of the Android SDK you are compiling with. It's possible for none of them to be selected, which would prevent the project from compiling. As for Java 1.6, I believe this is the level LibGDX is written to. See the note at the top of this page: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Manual-project-setup

Comment: Not really,its for Android, not libgdx. Android does not support java 1.7